# Wordpress site inherits main nav from other Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 sites. Both using the same theme. In "site A" I've built my navigation. In "site B" I'd like to make a call in the header.php file to inherit "site A" navigation.

I've tried putting this in "Site B" header.php, which loads the header, but it renders "Site B's" navigation.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/server/path/to/my/wordpress/site/siteA/header.php');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To make it dynamic, you would need to connect to the database of Site A and load the pages you need. Make a connection to the database where the Site A is, and since you are using the same theme, the same functions might work.

Comment: Connecting to the database, meaning, change the wp-config file to point to site A? But then all content(posts) would be inherited as well. Or do you mean create a connection outside of wordpress and query the nav items?

Comment: The better way to do that is curl()

Comment: No you wouldn't have changed wp-config. But you can just make your own php connection to any database, in this case it would be something like:
`<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","uname","pswd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
// sq query here
mysql_close($con);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pedro! I haven't worked with Curl often and turns out that was the easiest solution.

Here's what I did.

Created a getnav.php file and included the following:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once($root . "/path/to/siteA/wp-load.php");

  //RENDER PRIMARY NAV

  $defaults = array(
  'theme_location'  => '',
  'menu'            => 'Primary Menu', 
  'container'       => 'div', 
  'container_class' => 'menu-container', 
  'container_id'    => '',
  'menu_class'      => 'menu', 
  'menu_id'         => '',
  'echo'            => true,
  'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before'          => '',
  'after'           => '',
  'link_before'     => '',
  'link_after'      => '',
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul id=%1$s class=%2$s>%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 0,
  'show_home'   => 0,
  'walker'          => '');

   wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Then in "Site B" header.php file I make the Curl call:

```
$ch = curl_init("path/to/getnav.php");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$nav = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $nav;
```

Site A Navigation now Renders in Site B's header. Perfect!